# need help installing signed certificate on my linux serv

Tags: settings

I need help. I bought a signed certificate and got zip file with 4 crt file. now I do not know how to install.... I have no idea where I should copy these file or how to install the certificate to my debian 10 server

thanks in advance and sorry for my bad english... my german is much better

Comment: Hi, this is Elementary OS forum. There are plenty tutorials at YouTube and in Google which explains how to install a certificate on Debian server. If you need a help, let me know, but first try to look for on your own. All I can write that you should use some scp client like WinSCP (on a Windows) to upload certificates to a server. Then you must configure the Apache/Nginx virtual host config file responsible for displaying your website and put there the path to the certificates.

Comment: Thanks alot...I#m using apache and have Winscp on my widows 10. I was looking for the last 4 days everywhere but they aloways talk about creating and installin openssl certificate.
I wold really appreciate if you can help with totorial whrer to copy these 4 sct and the key file.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Apache on Debian then type in terminal:

```
sudo vim /etc/apache2/sites-available/example.com-ssl.conf
```

Press insert (inc) button on a keyboard to edit a file

Add like this at the end before closing . See example below:

```
            SecRuleEngine On
            SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/example.com/cert.pem
            SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/certs/example.com/privkey.pem
            SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/certs/example.com/chain.pem
    </VirtualHost>
```

Press Esc button on a keyboard, then type :x and hit Enter. It will save the file.

Then type in terminal:

```
sudo a2ensite example.com.conf
sudo apache2ctl configtest
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

Hope this explains how it should be done.
If you need the whole virtual host let me know, anyway you should read how to create virtual host in Apache for SSL.

Good example how to do it step by step is described here:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-the-apache-web-server-on-debian-9